# get TypeScript to generate named registers rather than anonymous registers

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I'm using Angular2 with SystemJS. I ran across a few issues which came down to the fact that TypeScript compiler generates anonymous registers rather than named registers:

```
...
System.register([], [...deps...], ...); //Generated by TypeScript compiler
System.register('myModule', [...deps...], ...); //How to do this?
...
```

This is for purpose of bundling. I like to do what Angular2 does already for my own components. Put multiple `System.register` calls in one minified file then import the root component.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: How are you compiling your source code? I'll keep looking because I'm curious as well. I haven't found anything concrete, but if using the tsc command, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Glad it's not possible with `tsc` since that's the node engine compiling it. I use Visual Studio which has a built in compiler. Not that would make any difference, since both of those compilers use tsconfig.json or MSBuild settings. The compiler options doesn't seem to have such option: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the "outFile" attribute in the TypeScript compiler configuration (i.e. tsconfig.json) with a file name.

In this case, all modules will be compiled into a single file (the specified one) and they will be named modules not anonymous ones.

Comment: Absolutely right. Interesting, TypeScript compiler recognizes that variation only if `--outFile` is present.